# Replacement with sed doesn't work as expected with variable expansion, extra characters appear

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I am having some trouble  with `sed`.

I need to replace a string in a file with something, and I have been partially successful with that, but I'm getting an extra string `t` in front of the actual output.

These are the commands I'm using

```
password=$(openssl rand -base64 8)
new_variable=$(echo -n "$password{s4lt}"  | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
to_be='#jbcrypt:$2a$10$mvkjME9eLxgvNu1f35SsSe5JKuVZaDf7xZX8DufaUMsMtDMzrGPUa'
with_be="<passwordHash>s4lt:${new_variable}</passwordHash>"
```

sting to be replaced

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$mvkjME9eLxgvNuMsMtDMzrGPUa</passwordHash>
```

with

```
<passwordHash>s4lt:c3b43792278faa66ffad524c6433bb755057455a0d43b4af4cab927dafc84f8a</passwordHash>
```

cmd used

```
sed -i "/$to_be/c \t\t$with_be" /var/lib/jenkins/users/admin/config.xml
```

outcome

```
t   <passwordHash>s4lt:c3b43792278faa66ffad524c6433bb755057455a0d43b4af4cab927dafc84f8a</passwordHash>
```

Comment: Please provide sample values of the variables, and enclose the variable names in `${}` -- at present it's unclear if the first variable is `${t}` or some longer name like `${to_}`, *etc*.

Comment: i have updated my question @agc

Answer (score 1):

Since your pattern contains `/`, you will have to tell `sed` to use another delimiter in the `/$to_be/` range expression. Here, I'm using `@` as the delimiter:

```
sed -i "\@$to_be@c\ \t\t$with_be" /var/lib/jenkins/users/admin/config.xml
```

Also note the backslash after the `c` command.

An alternate delimiter may be used in a range expression if it's escaped as I have shown above.  Almost any character may be used, except `\` and newline.  You should choose one that does not occur in the value of `$to_be`.

The `c` ("change") command has the form

```
range c\
text
```

GNU `sed` is forgiving in that it allows the replacement text to occur on the same line as the command itself, i.e. it allows for `range c\ text`.

Comment: `gnu sed` allows for [`range c text`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) so no, the backslash is not needed after `a`,`i` or `c`.

Comment: @don_crissti The backslash is needed, or the first `\t` will not be interpreted as a tab character by GNU `sed`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, the space after `c` is not a delimiter... They should update the manual. Their extensions often create more problems than they're trying to solve...

Comment: @don_crissti I'm honestly wondering if they are trying to "solve problems" rather than "try to be convenient". Although I don't like bashing GNU tools, I fully agree. It's things like these and the rearranging of command line options that gets me... :-)